# Removing the Visual Studio / Visual Web Developer 2010 Express debugger and debugging JavaScript in the browser's debugger

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, visual-web-developer-2010

When I set a break-point in my JavaScript code in the browser's debugger provided by its developer tools plug-in, I get a message saying that one or more processes are already attached to this, so it can't set a break-point or debug the code in the browser.

I know that if I run a deployed app, since it is not running in the Visual Studio environment, I can attach it to the browser's debugger.

But how do I debug an app already running in Debug mode inside Visual Studio / Visual Web Developer 2010 Express inside the browser?

Answer (score -1):

You want to use IE developer tools script debugging.
Try this:

Goto:

> Tools->Internet Options->Advanced->Under "Browsing"-> check both
>   options that starts with "Disable script debugging"

Open IE developer tools

> (Press F12 or Tools-> "F12 Developer tools")

Enable script debugging

> Open "script" tab and click button "start debugging"

If this works you will be able to debug your JS with IE developer tools.

Note: Why don't you use Chrome. It offers much better developer tools experience than IE.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I've already been using the IE JS debugger. My question is, it won't let me debug a script if I am running the code under the debug mode in Visual Studio/Visual Web Developer. How do I detach the VS debugger so that the IE debugger can be attached?

Comment: I don't think you need to explicitly detach the debugger from IE if you disable script debugging altogether and use IE dev tools script debugger instead. Follow the 1st step and it should work.